# How to float an element to the right in flexbox with multiple flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's say I have a flexbox set up like this:

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div id="item-1"></div>
    <div id="item-2"></div>
    <div id="item-3"></div>
</div>
```

I currently have the flex items set up using CSS like so:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|    1     |            2           |     3     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want the items to change to this layout when the screen reaches a certain size:

```
    --------------------
    |    3    |    1   |     
-----------------------------
|             2             |
-----------------------------
```

I know I can use `#item-3 {order:-1}` to move it to the beginning, but the part I'm having trouble with is floating element 1 to the right, above 2.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `#item-3 { order: 1 } #item-1 { order: 2 } #item-2 { order: 3, flex: 0 0 100% }`

Comment: This gives me the correct order of 3-1-2, but they're all stacked in a column when I use flex-direction: column. How can I get element 1 to float beside element 3?

Comment: @SorghumBean, your first ascii art table shows a row flexbox. Are you using row like the ascii art table suggests? Or column, like your comment suggests?

Comment: @drgogan I was using flex-direction: row for larger screens, and flex-direction: column for smaller screens, but the solution below worked out. Sorry, I should've clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

min-width is solution:

```css
.flexbox {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flexbox div {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #item-1, #item-3 {flex: 1;}
    #item-2 {flex: 2;}
    @media(max-width: 768px) {
      #item-1, #item-3 {
        order: 1;
      }
      #item-2 {
        order: 2;
        border-top: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="flexbox">
        <div id="item-1"></div>
        <div id="item-2"></div>
        <div id="item-3"></div>
    </div>
```